# Find llvm.pow.f64 in llvm IR

Tags: llvm

I'd like to find All function calls to llvm.pow.f64 function in llvm IR.Please suggest me a method to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here is a basic `FunctionPass` that finds all calls to functions:

```
class MyPass : public FunctionPass {
public:
    static char ID;

    MyPass()
        : FunctionPass(ID)
    {}

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
        for (Function::iterator bb = F.begin(), bb_e = F.end(); bb != bb_e; ++bb) {
            for (BasicBlock::iterator ii = bb->begin(), ii_e = bb->end(); ii != ii_e; ++ii) {
                if (CallInst *callInst = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&*ii)) {
                    Function *calledFunc = callInst->getCalledFunction();
                    errs() << "Calling function " << calledFunc->getName() << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

It prints the names of all functions called by the function it's working on. `getName` gives you a `StringRef`, so feel free to compare it to any value you want.